# Is reducing the complexity of a query by supporting it with javascript arrays of certain small tables worth it

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, arrays, join

I have a website that relies on data base queries pretty heavily when custom results are requested. Theses queries inner join about 6 different tables for certain data, the data from those tables remain static for long. I have been looking at making a javascript array and using method 1 to look the data up instead to remove some of those inner joins, not all of them, but just enough to make sure my database isn't overrun. I have an example query.

```
//search function
function FindData(WantedID) {
    var result = Array.filter(function( obj ) {
        return obj.ID== WantedID;
    });
    return result[0];
};

//query
SELECT ItemInfo1.SimpleDescription AS Item1Simple,
   ItemInfo1.FullDescription AS Item1Description,
   ItemInfo1.Name AS Item1Name,
   ItemInfo1.GoldCost AS Item1GoldCost,
   ItemInfo2.SimpleDescription AS Item2Simple,
   ItemInfo2.FullDescription AS Item2Description,
   ItemInfo2.Name AS Item2Name,
   ItemInfo2.GoldCost AS Item2GoldCost,
   ItemInfo3.SimpleDescription AS Item3Simple,
   ItemInfo3.FullDescription AS Item3Description,
   ItemInfo3.Name AS Item3Name,
   ItemInfo3.GoldCost AS Item3GoldCost,
   ItemInfo4.SimpleDescription AS Item4Simple,
   ItemInfo4.FullDescription AS Item4Description,
   ItemInfo4.Name AS Item4Name,
   ItemInfo4.GoldCost AS Item4GoldCost,
   ItemInfo5.SimpleDescription AS Item5Simple,
   ItemInfo5.FullDescription AS Item5Description,
   ItemInfo5.Name AS Item5Name,
   ItemInfo5.GoldCost AS Item5GoldCost,
   ItemInfo6.SimpleDescription AS Item6Simple,
   ItemInfo6.FullDescription AS Item6Description,
   ItemInfo6.Name AS Item6Name,
   ItemInfo6.GoldCost AS Item6GoldCost,
   ItemInfo7.SimpleDescription AS Item7Simple,
   ItemInfo7.FullDescription AS Item7Description,
   ItemInfo7.Name AS Item7Name,
   ItemInfo7.GoldCost AS Item7GoldCost,
   Spell11.Description AS Spell1Description,
   Spell11.Name AS Spell1Name,
   Spell11.SpellKey AS Spell1Key,
   Spell11.Cooldown AS Spell1Cooldown,
   Spell12.Description AS Spell2Description,
   Spell12.Name AS Spell2Name,
   Spell12.SpellKey AS Spell2Key,
   Spell12.Cooldown AS Spell2Cooldown,
   masteries.MasteryID,
   masteries.MasteryName,
   masteries.MasteryDescription,
   matchhistory.*,
   championdb.ChampName,
   player.Alias,
   player.RoleSlug,
   player.Region,
   player.AltRegion,
   player.playerid,
   player.SummonerIcon,
   teams.Name,
   teams.ID AS TeamID,
   player.League,
   player.Division,
   player.Points,
   player.isFreshBlood,
   player.isHotStreak,
   player.isVeteran,
   player.Wins,
   player.Losses,
   player.FirstChamp,
   player.SecondChamp,
   player.ThirdChamp
FROM matchhistory
   INNER JOIN player ON matchhistory.SummonerID = player.playerid
   INNER JOIN teams ON player.Team = teams.ID
   INNER JOIN summonerspells AS Spell11
      ON matchhistory.Spell1 = Spell11.SpellID
   INNER JOIN summonerspells AS Spell12
      ON matchhistory.Spell2 = Spell12.SpellID
   INNER JOIN items AS ItemInfo1 ON matchhistory.Item0 = ItemInfo1.ItemID
   INNER JOIN items AS ItemInfo2 ON matchhistory.Item1 = ItemInfo2.ItemID
   INNER JOIN items AS ItemInfo3 ON matchhistory.Item2 = ItemInfo3.ItemID
   INNER JOIN items AS ItemInfo4 ON matchhistory.Item3 = ItemInfo4.ItemID
   INNER JOIN items AS ItemInfo5 ON matchhistory.Item4 = ItemInfo5.ItemID
   INNER JOIN items AS ItemInfo6 ON matchhistory.Item5 = ItemInfo6.ItemID
   INNER JOIN items AS ItemInfo7 ON matchhistory.Item6 = ItemInfo7.ItemID
   INNER JOIN masteries ON matchhistory.KeystoneID = masteries.MasteryID
   INNER JOIN championdb ON matchhistory.ChampID = championdb.ChampID
ORDER BY matchhistory.TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I'm looking to reduce the item inner joins as their are 6 items in the main table, and i need to inner join each time to get the specific data for each item. In Total there is 200 items. I am using mysql, I am also looking at replacing inner join with WHERE ID IN to increase query speed. I can cache the array results also to make it faster, the array data is made with a once off query. My database server is separate from my webapp server

[image: Image of my explain and other details]

Comment: So it looks like you are selecting everything on each query? Doesn't sound right... Are you looking for a way to add `WHERE` clause or for a way to perform caching? What is your question?

Comment: I am looking for a way to improve this query, or whether me removing all item references and storing the item table in a array that is looked up and cached on the webapp server is worth it?

Comment: That would largely depend on how much data is in your DB, how often you query it and many other things. If you don't have performance issues then there is no point in fixing it. If you do, or if you foresee those issues in the future then fix it.

Comment: Ya I am planning for launch, the items table is 200 rows with about 4 columns, i don't think having all that in my query is worth it

Comment: @Djinnes -- on most db systems 200 rows and 4 columns will fit in memory -- this is tiny.  Is this really the size of your DB?  If so don't per-optimize it isn't big enough.

Comment: How will you be feeding the data in? If you feed one match per day, then it is no problem; feeding hundreds will give you performance issues after some time... probably months if not years

Comment: In general you should let the engine do the optimization for you and a join is going to be faster than a `WHEN ... IN (...)`

Comment: @bc004346 -- your comment does not make sense to me.  You are saying that if you add hundreds it will have a scaling issue, but there are countless relational systems that don't and most have more than 5 joins.  Consider (for example) your local cell tower -- there are hundreds of phone calls connecting there every hour -- and it has more than 5 joined tables.

Comment: There are about 1000 matches a day, most tables are small, the matches table is the biggest, I want to store the small tables in memory to stop inner joins and help just filtering the match history table. I delete matches after 3 weeks to clear up the database, active match history table usually has 18000 records

Comment: In this case I would be really concerned about why you query every single row every single time. You either need to introduce a `WHERE` clause or else cache some data

Comment: the small tables should stay in memory unless you are partitioning -- which your db is to small for -- do you have indexes on your tables?

Comment: My database is on a separate server, so it has it's resources, both database server and web app server are scaled vertically. The database server takes a lot of strain due to the complexity and volume of the queries, this leads to my web app server waiting for a response for longer. I thought that reducing the complexity of my query and using a in memory database for small tables on the web app server might assist in the overall performance to be improved. was wondering if my thinking was correct

Comment: I have all indexes on my tables and they are all normalized, normally I add 4 where conditions that sort it by columns on matchhistory,

Comment: When you do an explain on the query are you doing seeks in all cases?

Comment: Yes, every query is limited to 10.

Comment: I don't think you are answering my question did you run EXPLAIN against your query? (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan)  If you did please post it here or link to a gist of it so we can see what is slowing down your query.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I attached the the explain with the full query, do you think this query can be improved at all and will it scale well?

Comment: @Djinnes execute your query with "EXPALIN" statement at the start and post outputs, its more informative performance wise that query itself. joining 5 tables eaven on prety large tables is okay as long as its properly indexed. sometime too much indexes can ge you in to the trouble as well

Comment: @Djinnes your query is prety simple, you are matching everything against main table, with proper indexes it must work fast eaven with larger tables.

Comment: Have you tested telling the *DBMS* about the "array" of  items by having a (properly indexed) table for (summoner_id, item_id)?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing several mistakes

1) you fetch whole DB table join into a javascript and than you try to find specific match.
Thats **very bad** idea performance wise, especialy if you expect your tables to grow. Where clausule is there for a reason.

2) your DB tables are **not** properly indexed it seems.
based on your explain mysql is doing full table scan on player table and than scaning match history table adding multiple rows from other tables, creating temorary table for sorting (might be eaven Disk Table), sorting it (wihout index) and than fetching your 10 lines of data.

What you need is to add index on matchtable on ID colum you should be matching and than add timestamp colum to enable sorting by index. this have to be combined with where clausule containing specific ID your are searching for.

But .... based on sections of code you provided I am not sure that your problem is with database, Because eaven small instance of mysql have to handle this in few ms.